# Importing dynamically generated content into Flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I have a website that uses some JavaScript APIs to create flash-based charts (namely Im using annotated timeline from google's charts api). Now, however, the client wants a flash-based slide show that embeds some of the features of the website.

Is there a way to import the flash graphs generated by a JavaScript api into my completely-flash slide-show ?

I know I can import data from a MySQL database into flash, but are there any chart generation libraries that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly dependent on how you're accessing the data, whether you can format the raw output of your data to fit another implementation.

I'm not familiar with ways to import JavaScript based charts into Flash but I recomend looking into [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/).